# Stairs vs staircase - in what context should they be used?

Tags: phrase-usage

What should I say - we are climbing down the staircase or we are climbing down the stairs?

In which context should those words be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good deal of overlap in actual use, but as a rule of thumb you may think of  *stairs* as the surfaces on which you place your feet (I hope it is your feet!), while a *staircase* is an  architectural element comprising both the stairs and the visible and hidden elements which support, supplement and ornament the stairs.

(Technically, the surfaces are *treads*, and *stairs* may include both treads and *risers*—the vertical surfaces which close the gaps between treads; but only carpenters and architects have occasion to draw this distinction.)

You climb, ascend, descend, mount, bound up, tumble down, stand on or pose on *the stairs*; you design, build, install, remove, tear out, or admire a *staircase*.